# undefined index for database field

Tags: php, mysql

The below code show warning undefined index for my database field name 'zatitle' spelling is correct in both code and database. I can not find out the error please help.

```
    include('connect.php');
    dbConnect(); 

    $myquery=mysql_query("SELECT zaid,zatext, MAX(zatitle) FROM announcements") or die(mysql_error());
     if (mysql_num_rows($myquery) == '1') {
     $asession=mysql_fetch_array($myquery);
     $ses = $asession['zatitle'];
       if($ses=='1'){
        $one='2013-2014';
       }elseif($ses=='2'){
        $one='2014-2015';
       }elseif($ses=='3'){
        $one='2015-2016';
       }elseif($ses=='4'){
        $one='2016-2017';
       }
```

For this code the warning is problem given below

> Notice: Undefined index: zatitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\home.php on line 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `alias` for column with `MAX`.

```
$myquery=mysql_query("SELECT zaid,zatext, MAX(zatitle) as zatitle FROM announcements") or die(mysql_error());
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a query like this

```
$myquery=mysql_query("SELECT zaid,zatext, MAX(zatitle) as zatitle FROM announcements")
```

because if you select Max(zatitle) then the result will also come as Max(zatitle)